# Flash CC HTML5 ought to be simple gotoAndPlay

Tags: javascript, html, flash, flash-cc

I'm creating an Javascript/HTML5-game in Flash CC.

I have an Info-screen with a button. This Infoscreen is a movieclip from the library with a linkname "CloseBtn". The following script is on frame 8 in this movieclip:

```
<code>
this.stop();
var closeBtn=new lib.CloseBtn();
closeBtn.x=130;
closeBtn.y=150;
closeBtn.stop();
this.addChild(closeBtn);
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event)
{
        this.gotoAndPlay(9);    
});
</code>
```

As you probably have guessed this should gotoAndPlay frame 9 in the InfoScreen when the button is clicked. But it does not work! Am I thinkg wrong when combining code with timeline?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

The solution is the keyword "this" before the button when assigning the eventListener. Took me about 8 hours of frustrated code analysis to find out.

```
    this.closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event)
    {
        this.gotoAndPlay(9);    
    });
```