# Adobe flash professional CC gotoAndPlay bug

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe

First of all, hello.

I have to develop a simple game in flash, usign HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript. The game, however poor, is pretty much implemented. My problem is, that after you play the game, it shows a try again button, designed to go back to frame 1. When i click the button it goes to frame 1 and returns to frame 25. Any ideas?

[image]

The last frame has this code:

```
var root = this;
this.stop();
this.tryAgain_btn.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler);
function mouseClickHandler(e) {
     root.gotoAndPlay(0);
};
```

And frame one has this code:

```
var self = this;
this.stop();    
this.play_btn.addEventListener("click", go);

function go()
{
    self.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing this in html5 or in actionscript? Based on your picture of your timeline it looks like you're using actionscript, not a HTML5 Canvas with javascript.

Besides that, try using gotoAndStop(1); rather than gotoAndPlay(0) and removing your stop(); methods. Let me know in the comments if it works but since your question is slightly unclear I don't have a grasp on what you're doing.

**EDIT**

Example, in case you don't understand:

```
var root = this;
this.stop();
this.tryAgain_btn.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler);

function mouseClickHandler(e) {
    root.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Take a shot at using

```
this.tryAgain_btn.addEventListener("click", function (event)
{
        this.gotoAndPlay(1);    
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant actionscript. However, i've tried, gotoAndPlay(1), and gotoAndStop(1), and none works. It goes to the selected frame and comes back to the tryAgain frame.

Comment: Could it maybe be that you're writing gotoAndStop(0) rather than gotoAndStop(1) since there is no frame 0? Try gotoAndStop(1) and let me know

Comment: Perhaps try changing your eventListeners. Where you write "this.tryAgain_btn.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler);" try writing "this.tryAgain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);". Although I doubt this would be the issue since you state that your buttons are functional. I feel like it's an error in the code in your first frame that isn't posted in the question

Comment: Also make sure to import flash.events.MouseEvent when trying this.

Comment: In your "function go() { } " you never bind it to e. "function go(e) { }"

Comment: I've tried it all, none of it works. And the only code i have in frame one are that five lines.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557262/flash-cc-html5-ought-to-be-simple-gotoandplay and try following their structure on creating event listeners. I've added an example on how you can change it in "edit 2".

Comment: I've seen that question, and that doesn't work. "this" is not recognized inside the function, that's why i use that "var root = this" line.

Comment: Also, let me explain something else, and maybe you can understand better. Even if i remove the "tryAgain" frame, the game ends and gets back to the main menu, but if i press the play button again, the same happens. It's like it is impossible to play two times.

Comment: I'm stumped. When using Flash CC in the past I used to always run into issues like this and 99% of the time they were present simply because of a dumb error that had nothing to do with my code. I recommend using HTML5 in a different form, perhaps in NetBeans or some other IDE or even just a normal text editor and making simple games with shapes to start out. Since you stated that your game is poor I'm seeing that you're learning to code and I recommend you start in more advance program, since it's no longer supported by Adobe and is getting more outdated day by day. Save yourself that stress

Comment: I wish i could, i'm in my Masters degree in Informatic Engineering, and this discipline can only be done using flash. Javascript code all the class can do, getting flash to work is what makes us waste 3 days, in something that could be done in 20 minutes. Anyway, thanks for your help :)